# asp.net setting onclick of input button dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, input

I have some dynamic buttons that look like this:

```
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Click me"
    onclick="window.open('somelink');" />
```

I need to be able to change 'somelink' from the code behind.

How is that done? 
I know `Request.Form["button"]` gets the button but how to set the onlick property?

Comment: `<input type='button'/>` wont postback/submit. Use `<%= %>` or `<%# %>` expressions

Comment: I do not need postback. hence why not using <asp:button>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add runat="server" and you can access that link from code behind

```
<input runat="server" type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Click me"
    onclick="window.open('somelink');" />
```

and if you want to change the onclick attribute then you do this in code behind

```
button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('someOtherLink');")
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the click handler on a button should be done when the page loads, not when the form is submitted. Before you can access your button from C#, you need to add `runat="server"`. After that, you may access its properties:

HTML

```
<input runat="server" type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Click me"
    onclick="window.open('somelink');" />
```

C#

```
button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('[DynamicValueHere]');");
```

Comment: cannot find 'button' only works for asp:button type. I need it for input type=button

Comment: have tried HtmlButton button = FindControl("button") as HtmlButton;
        button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('link')"); and it doesnt find it. it is null. yes runat=server

Comment: @user1468537, you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Assigning **any** html control and ID and specifying `runat="server"` will allow you to access it from the code-behind by ID.

Comment: yes but c# does not recognize the 'button' variable in the context above

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<asp:Button id="button" Text="Click me"  OnClick="window.open('somelink');" />
```

**and**
from code behind

```
button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('somelink');");
```

And you can add whatever you want in place of `somelink`.
that's it.

Comment: I do not want postback. Just want a button that will open a new window with a dynamic link. If asp:button's postback can be toggled off (which i dont think it can) then yes I could use that.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you pass `<%=SomeUrl%>` inside `window.open` like this `window.open(<%=SomeUrl%>)`

Comment: have tried but it seems it never gets assigned. as in its just blank, even though i can see the variable value being correct.